# find overlapping features in one feature class

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy

I am attempting to identify overlapping features in one feature class. As a Searchcursor this code works fine, but when I convert to an update cursor I get "StopIteration: iteration not started" error when cur.updateRow(e1[1]) is called.

```
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, ["SHAPE@", "Working_comments"]) as cur:
        for e1,e2 in itertools.combinations(cur,2):
            if e1[0].overlaps(e2[0]):
               e1[1] = "overlaps"
            cur.updateRow(e1[1])
```

Comment: have you tried moving in `cur.updateRow(e1[1])` to inside the `if`? alt, maybe there's no current row to the UpdateCursor `cur` object, because you're using `itertools.combinations()`. can you check the type of `e1[1]`? Or, maybe the best idea is to run `cur.updateRow(e1)` instead of the indexed `e1[1]`

Comment: I think the best idea is to make sure what you are passing to `cur.updateRow()` is actually a row of type tuple, so probably pass in `e1` instead of `e1[1]`

Comment: @ehacinom I have tried moving the cur.updateRow(e1[1]) to inside the if but I get the same results. I think the issue is as you have suggested that there is no current row for the UpdateCursor because I am using the itertools.combinations() but I am not sure how to fix that. I checked and e1 is of type 'list' and e1[1] is 'unicode'. thanks for the help!

Comment: hm, have you tried using 2 for loops instead of itertools.combinations?